# Application tried to present modally an active controller, why this code is crashing, knows anything about it?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uialertcontroller

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Language"
                              message:@""
                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:

    for (int j =0 ; j<val.count; j++)
    {
        NSString *titleString = val[j];
        UIAlertAction * action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:titleString style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                  {

                                  }];


        [alertController addAction:action];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please format code as code and not as normal text.

Comment: What error you are getting on crash? Log the crash report as well

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Application tried to present modally an active controller-This error m getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only present the alert controller **once**. Move it out of your loop, and it should work.